# BigInteger with fastapi and sqlmodel

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, fastapi, pydantic, sqlmodel

I'm using FastAPI with SQLModel which is based on pydantic, SQLAlchemy and type hints. And I'm trying to create a `BitInteger` (`int64` is enough) column. How do I do that?

My sql model declaration looks like that

```py
class ItemBase(sqlmodel.SQLModel):
    name: str
    price: int  


class Item(ItemBase, table=True):
    id: int = sqlmodel.Field(default=None, primary_key=True)


class ItemCreate(ItemBase):
    pass
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 8):

From [the issue documenting how to make BigIntegers](https://github.com/tiangolo/sqlmodel/issues/191) work with SQLModel:

```
id: int = Field(default_factory=next_val, sa_column=Column(BigInteger(), primary_key=True, autoincrement=False))
```

You might need to adjust it slightly for your usage, but using a specific sqlalchemy column type seems to be the way.

Comment: Thanks this works: `id: int = Field(sa_column=Column(BigInteger()))`